# show and then hide text JS Jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, hide, javascript, show

I want to do so when you just entered index.php it will appear a text for 10 seconds, and then it will hide, how to do so? and hide like slowly fine i have jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mySectionToFade = $('#myFadingSection');

    setTimeout(function(){ mySectionToFade.fadeOut() }, 10000);

})
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
<p class="text">My text</p>

<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.text').fadeOut();
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: He wants to hide it after 10 seconds if i understand the question correctly... so the opposite of what you do :)

Comment: I don't think you can reference `$` within a setTimeout. Can you? Thought it was out of scope.

Comment: @Patrick: $ and jQuery is in the global (window) scope, so yes, you can.

Comment: Right you are. Gave you a +1. For some reason it wasn't working that way when I was testing. Now it is. Thanks.